# SELECT command not being recognized for some reason.

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

For some reason, every time I try to run this, there is any error saying that the SQL statement at line 4, column 3 (SELECT) has been ignored. Also says, "YEAR": Invalid Identifier. Year is another column that exists on the same form. I am trying to make a column that displays the YEAR with a hyphen like for example this: "17-".

```
 DECLARE
  TERRA_NUMBER VARCHAR2(40);
BEGIN
 SELECT CONCAT(YEAR , '-' )
 INTO TERRA_NUMBER FROM DUAL;
  RETURN TERRA_NUMBER;
END;
```

Comment: can you explain the steps you done to solve your problem

Comment: it seems you forgot the FROM clause in the SELECT (based on the comment that YEAR is a column)

Comment: You are selecting from `dual` table. No year column there. Why returning from anonymous block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

First, there is no `YEAR` variable in Oracle.  Perhaps you intend `TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY')`.

Second, an anonymous programming block does not return a value.  So, `RETURN` is inappropriate.

If this is part of a function or stored procedure you should show the entire definition.

Comment: I didn't actually realize that I had FROM DUAL written. I'm actually trying to get YEAR from the table that I already have called APPLICATION.

Comment: Thank you, for pointing this out my code got validated. Now I just have to worry about getting only one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create FindYear function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FindYear RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
TERRA_NUMBER VARCHAR2(40);
BEGIN 

SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY') , '-' )
 INTO TERRA_NUMBER FROM DUAL;
 RETURN(TERRA_NUMBER);
END;
/
```

[image]